# How to display a html tag if JSF conditon is true?

Tags: jsf-2

I want to display `<span>Lorem Ipsum</span>` if a backing-bean value is **NOT** empty.

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{not empty pubController.location}">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</h:outputText>
```

The Lorem Ipsum does never display. Apparently, it also doesn't work if I remove the NOT in my condition.

FYI: Before I run the h:outputText, I simply print the boolean statements. It prints exactly what I expect. True for the values which are NOT empty. Also, the rendered-condition works also with an h:form tag as I would expect it. Looks like the h:outputText is inappropriate in this case, is it?

Is there a better approach than using h:outputText for what I want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't work because `h:outputText` doesn't accept child elements as stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/jsp/h/outputText.html):

> If this element has children, they must be ignored by default.
>   Implementions may provide a configuration option that allows this
>   element to render its children.

Trying with the following code should solve your problem:

```
<h:outputText value="Lorem Ipsum" rendered="#{not empty pubController.location}"/>
```

Note that you could also do the following:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty pubController.location}">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</h:panelGroup>
```

That would be useful if you need to display a more complicated structure than a simple `span` element.

Comment: Yes, you're alternative works, since it considers the span tag, too. Great. Thanks.

Comment: The `<h:outputText>` doesn't generate any `<span>` if no client side attributes are specified. You seem to be expecting the otherwise.

Comment: You would have to do `<span><h:outputText ... /></span>` to generate a `<span>`.